# Show that τ = {A ⊂ R : ∃N ∈ N, ∀n ≥ N, 1/n ∈ A} ∪ {∅} is a topology for R. n

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

To show that τ is a topology for R, we have to show that the empty set and R are open. We also have to show that intersection of two open sets is open and that the union of open sets is open. I am having trouble proving these latter two conditions.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:

If $A\subseteq\mathbb R$ is a nonempty element of $\tau$ then eventually $n^{-1}\in A$.

Note that this must also be the case for every $B\subseteq\mathbb R$ with $A\subseteq B$. Use this to prove that unions of sets in $\tau$ are also sets in $\tau$.

If $A,B\in\tau$ with $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$ then eventually $n^{-1}\in A$ and eventually $n^{-1}\in B$. Can you prove that eventually $n^{-1}\in A\cap B$?

Comment: I am unsure on how to use these hints. What I need to prove is that, for the intersection of A and B, there exists a natural number P such that for every p greater than or equal to P, p^-1 is in the intersection. Now, what I think you are saying is that, eventually, p^-1 will belong to both of them. Not sure yet how this helps.

Comment: Indeed, it will belong to both of them ($A$ and $B$), wich means exactly that it belongs to the intersection, as you are asked to prove.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to prove the sets you specified are open per se; you want to consult the definition of $\tau$ to show a finite intersection or arbitrary union of sets is in $\tau$. If a finite intersection or arbitrary union of elements of $\tau$ is itself an element of $\tau$, $\it{then}$ a finite intersection or arbitrary union of sets is open in the topology.

In total there are four things you need to show for $\tau$ to be a topology on $\Bbb{R}$. You need to show that:

$(1)$ $\tau$ contains the Empty Set 
$(2)$ $\tau$ contains $\Bbb{R}$ 
  $(3)$ A finite intersection of elements of $\tau$ is an element of $\tau$
 $(4)$ An arbitrary union of elements of $\tau$ is an element of $\tau$

$(1)$ It should be clear that $\emptyset \in \tau.$ $(2)$ Next, we know $\Bbb{R} \in \tau$ because we can choose $N=1$ and it is true that $\frac{1}{n} \in \Bbb{R}$ for all $n \geq N$. $(3)$ Given any two elements of $\tau$, say $A_1, A_2$, we know there exists $N_1, N_2$ respectively such that $\frac{1}{n} \in A_1, \space \frac{1}{m} \in A_2$ for all $n\geq N_1$ and $m \geq N_2$. If without loss of generality we take $N_1 = \max\{N_1,N_2 \}$ then it is obvious that $\frac{1}{n} \in A_1 \cap A_2$ for all $n \geq N_1$. Hence, $A_1 \cap A_2 \in \tau$.

Once you show $(4)$ you are done.